Reference Request for Proof of Landau' Formula
I tried to find a proof for Landau' Formula (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandausFormula.html). Original paper (1911) is in German and I searched classic books (Montgomery, Titchmarsh, Ivic) and none has a proof: In Titchmarsh's Ch14 it is mentioned that a proof exists "in the books of Landau and Ingham". There is no explicit reference in Titchmarsh's book what book(s) he is talking about but the only book I guessed is https://www.amazon.com/Distribution-Numbers-Cambridge-Mathematical-Library/dp/0521397898 but still it has no proof for it.
I would appreciate it if someone please let me know where can I find a proof.
My reason for study this formula is to study it before studying S. M. Gonek's paper (https://oa.mg/work/10.1090/conm/143/1210528).

Landau's proof is similar but easier than Gonek Theorem 1; Landau starts on the segment $[2+qi, 2+iT]$ for a fixed constant $0<q<2$ (which Gonek takes $1$) and ignores the $x$ dependence since for Landau any such goes into the $O$ (eg Landau starts at $2$ so gets an $x^2$ while Gonek starts at $1+c/\log x$ to get just an $x \log x \log \log x$) and just takes the integral on abscissa to $-\infty$ and then looks carefully at the part from $-1$ to $2$ since there the standard approximation of $\zeta'/\zeta$ in terms of nearby zeroes is a bit more delicate; Gonek proof is a refinement of Landau

while I am not really fluent in German, Landau's paper quoted in Wolfram Alpha Landau, E. "Über die Nullstellen der Zetafunction." Math. Ann. 71, 548-564, 1911. is very easy to read regardless of any German skills as there are pretty much only formulas

@Conrad, Thanks a lot :)
